# Java and enum with scanner

Tags: java, enums

I have a problem with an enum. I have a class `Type` where I have two enums: `RIGHT` and `LEFT`. 
In other class I have object of class `Type`, named `value`. 
I have a loop:

```
if (currentLvl.verify(value)) {
    totalPoint++;
}
```

where `currentLvl.verify(value)` is a method which verifies if value is correct. My problem is how I can get `value` from user. I want the user, before loop if, to write his value and after that if `value` is correct, `totalPoint++`. I want use a scanner but I can't do `value = scanner.nextInt();`.  How I can get `value` from the user and his value imput to variable `value`?

Comment: What is an example of a valid user input?

Comment: example valid user input is: 0 or 1. I want to 0 represents LEFT and 1 represents RIGHT

Comment: You don't have any problem with enums. At the moment you have a problem with user input, and not a very clear one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the `valueOf()` method to convert the String to the enum, something like this:

```
Type value = Type.valueOf(scanner.next().toUpperCase());
```

Or if the user is entering the enum value then use the `values()` array

```
Type value = Type.values()[scanner.nextInt()];
```

Comment: Hi objects, dependency on ordinal positions of enum values could lead to issues especially during change requests, i.e. insertion of CENTER before LEFT would change positions of LEFT from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.print("Enter a value: ");

String userInput = stdin.readLine();

System.out.println(userInput);
```

In enum class:

```
public enum EType{
  private String value;

  LEFT("left"), RIGHT("right");

  private EType(String value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue(){
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

OR:

```
public enum EType{
  private int value;

  LEFT(1), RIGHT(0);

  private EType(int value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue(){
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Comparing enum value and user value:

```
if(LEFT.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)){
  // do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

OR:

```
if(userInput == EType.LEFT.getValue()){
  // do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a minute to figure out what you were saying, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
public enum Type {
    LEFT, RIGHT;

    public static Type getTypeByOrdinal(int ordinal) {
        for(Type t : Type.values()) {
            if(t.ordinal() == ordinal) {
                return t;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

You can now scan in integers:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int userInput = sc.nextInt(); // Assume userInput = 1
Type t1 = Type.getTypeByOrdinal(userInput);
System.out.println(t1); // => RIGHT

userInput = sc.nextInt(); // Assume userInput = 0
Type t2= Type.getTypeByOrdinal(userInput);
System.out.println(t2); // => LEFT
```

Comment: Hi Ian, dependency on ordinal positions of enum values could lead to issues especially during change requests, i.e. insertion of CENTER before LEFT would change positions of LEFT from 0 to 1.

Comment: @ChinBoon I completely agree! I based my decision to use ordinals off his comment on his original post. I realize the way that you've done it is definitely safer, I just was trying to write whatever would make sense in the context of his code. That being said, the accepted answer also uses ordinals.